# How do you remove certain characters & text within a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
 <Line Text="***********TITLE************" /> 
 <Line Text="***REPORT****" /> 
 <Line Text=TEXT" /> 
 <Line Text=" " /> 
 <Line Text="TEXT" /> 
 <Line Text="TEXT" /> 
 <Line Text=" " /> 
 <Line Text="TEXT" /> 
 <Line Text="TEXT" /> 
 <Line Text=" " />
```

I am looking to create a batch file to remove "`<Line Text="`" AND "`" />`" resulting in file looking like this:

```
 ***********TITLE************
 ***REPORT****
 TEXT

 TEXT
 TEXT

 TEXT
 TEXT
```

I have tried the following:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=^<Line Text"
set "replace="

set "textFile=test.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

Results in deleting all text within the file.  I did try removing the LESS THAN & GREATER THAN signs.  Somewhat works, however, still not able to get the desired outcome.

Comment: *"I have tried multiple batch scripts"* -- please [edit] your question and share a [mcve] of your coding attempts. Hint: take a look at [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html); e. g.: `for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=/=" %%I in ("file.txt") do echo %%I`...

Comment: @aschipfl Best script I have used so far updated/edited to original post.

Comment: In my experience bash regex is hard try with pandoc https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html

Comment: I would advise you not to try reading from and writing to the same file. If something goes wrong you could lose content. Please see my answer, which was posted first and uses a similar method to the one you've accepted. In my opinion it is more robust, and takes account of your possible typo in your input text file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You need to [escape](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) `<` and `>` in the search and replace strings like `^>` and `^>`, because they appear unquoted when variables `%search%` and `%replace%` are expanded.
2. An `=`-sign cannot occur in the search string as it separates search and replace strings.

Therefore I would use [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split the lines, like this, for example:

```cmd
rem /* Split each line at quotation marks `"` (this requires the
rem    undocumented unquoted option string syntax of `for /F`): */
for /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%I in ('type "test.txt" ^& ^> "test.txt" rem/') do (
    >> "test.txt" echo(%%I
)
```

Comment: So is my understanding correct that the "="; there is no removing it whatsoever from the text file?

Comment: Alright, this is great thank you!  I have removed everything I want to this point, now just needing to remove the "=".  If able to assist with that batch code?

Comment: You're welcome! My code should already remove the `=` since they appear in front of the first `"`...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of examples to help you out.

This example is for the provided text file format and content only:

```
@Echo Off
Set "InputFile=infile.txt"
Set "OutputFile=outfile.txt"
If Exist "%InputFile%" ((For /F UseBackQTokens^=2Delims^=^=^" %%A In (
            "%InputFile%")Do Set /P "=%%A"<NUL&Echo()>"%OutputFile%")
```

If you have a typo on line `3`, and you really missed the opening doublequote, then:

```
@Echo Off
Set "InputFile=infile.txt"
Set "OutputFile=outfile.txt"
If Exist "%InputFile%" ((For /F UseBackQTokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In (
            "%InputFile%")Do Set /P "=%%A"<NUL&Echo()>"%OutputFile%")
```

In either case, you should only need to modify the filenames/paths on lines `2` and `3` as required.